# Presenting a new view controller without infinitely stacking them?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am working on an app where it is kind of like a website. There is a menu that every viewcontroller has in it and that needs to switch to the correct view.

There is no concept of back in my application. Thus, if I use UINavigation to push a view, I end up stacking up lots of views.

Same problem if I add the vc as a child or present it, you end up with hundreds of vcs after a while.

What is a way I can design this to safely have only 1 view at any given time?

Thanks

Comment: Are they all the same view controller class? If so, instead of pushing, adding, or presenting another, simply use one and provide it new data to display.

Comment: Why can't you simply assign the required new view controller to your `appDelegate.window.rootViewController` property?

Comment: I have 4 mini games and I want their gui  logic each in separate classes. So I want each game to deal with its own gui components to avoid clutter.

Comment: If I do that, ARC will not destroy the previous root view.

Comment: @Milo Why do you think that the old root controller won't be deallocated when setting a new one?

Comment: Why not?  What is holding a reference?  The other approach is to simply create an empty root view controller and associated view then provide methods in that VC that dismiss the current sub view controller and present the required new one

Comment: You could implement UIViewController containment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this.

Add this to all your controllers that have access to the navigation controller. When you want to push a new controller, instead of using `pushViewController:animated` you can use this. You can modify the code to take `animated` as a parameter aswell.

```
- (void)pushIfNotInStack:(UIViewController*)viewController
{
    BOOL isInStack = NO;
    NSMutableArray * vcStack = [self.navigationController.viewControllers mutableCopy];
    for (NSInteger i = 1 ; i <vcStack.count; i++){
        if ([viewController isKindOfClass:[[vcStack objectAtIndex:i]class]]) {
            [vcStack replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:viewController];
            isInStack = YES;
        }
    }

    if(isInStack){
        [self.navigationController setViewControllers:vcStack];
        [self.navigationController popToViewController:viewController animated:YES];
    } else {
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a tab bar view controller and hide the tab bar.

A tab view controller can have a number of children view controllers. You can add these children view controllers in storyboard or in code.

[image]

You can use your menu to choose which child view controller you want to display. The children view controllers are indexed from 0 to n - 1, where n is the number of view controllers. If you want to display the view controller at index i:

```
[self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:i];
```

Don't forget to hide your tab bar in each child view controller's `viewDidLoad`

Comment: I don't think you understand the question. A tab controller is not appropriate.

Comment: @rmaddy Do you mean you have several view controllers, and have a menu to control which view controller to show?

Answer (score 0):

You can also sublass your `UINavigationController` `class` and override `pushViewController:animated:` method as follow:

```
- (void)pushViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated {

    if (self.viewControllers.count > <#the number of controllers you want to keep in memory eg. 20 #>) {
        NSMutableArray *mutableViewControllers = [self.viewControllers mutableCopy];
        //remove 2 last controllers in controller stack (from the bottom)
        [mutableViewControllers removeObjectsAtIndexes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:NSMakeRange(0, 2)]];
        self.viewControllers = [mutableViewControllers copy];
    }

    [super pushViewController:viewController animated:animated];
}
```

This approach gurantees you to `alloc init` controllers in normal way and don't bother about they pointers to memory.